# Transform empty list to empty string in jolt

Tags: json, transform, jolt

The use case is sometimes I will get an empty list as the input and instead of getting null as output for some specs, I want either empty string or no output instead of null.

And if the input is not an empty list, I want the spec to transform the input and give the results.

Input:

```
[]
```

Specs:

```
[{
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "comments": "Sample values."
      }
    }
},

  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "a": "[&1].A",
        "b": "[&1].B",
        "c": "[&1].C",
        "comments": "[&1].comments"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

desired output:

Output received:

```
null
```

Is there a way to get nothing in the output if the input is empty list?

Comment: No, not possible. If there's no error and nothing will be returned, then `null` returns by default, this is the mechanism as designed to do so.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, BarbarosÖzhan